# ¿mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given?

Tags: php, login, xampp

Tengo mi código php para la conexión a la base de datos pero me manda ese error en la linea 13 y 14, no encuentro una solución, les adjunto mi codigo

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","SaveMe");
$Usuario = $_POST["Usuario"];
$Contraseña = $_POST["Contraseña"];
$Nombre = $_POST["Nombres"];
$Apellido = $_POST["Apellidos"];
$Edad = $_POST["Edad"];
$Numero = $_POST["Numero"];
$Correo = $_POST["Correo"];
linea 13  $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO usuarios (Usuario, Contraseña, Nombres, Apellidos, Edad, Numero, Correo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
linea 14 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssiis", $Usuario, $Contraseña, $Nombre, $Apellido, $Edad, $Numero, $Correo);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: El prepare te esta devolviendo false, hay algo mas ahi... probablemente la conexion este mal..

Comment: Me doy cuenta que es solo en los $statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando *programas*, dos cosas pueden pasar: o tú controlas al código, o el código te controla a ti.

Siempre es bueno optar por la segunda opción, estableciendo un control estricto del código, de modo que siempre sepas lo que está ocurriendo.

Ahí vamos:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","SaveMe");

/*
    *Control 0 (pendiente): Sería bueno que controles si las variables del POST tienen datos.
    *No lo he hecho porque la tabla puede admitir algunos valores en blanco
    *Al menos debes controlar que aquellos valores esenciales no estén vacíos
*/
$Usuario = $_POST["Usuario"];
$Contraseña = $_POST["Contraseña"]; //Yo no usaría la ñ, podría dar problema en algún escenario
$Nombre = $_POST["Nombres"];
$Apellido = $_POST["Apellidos"];
$Edad = $_POST["Edad"];
$Numero = $_POST["Numero"];
$Correo = $_POST["Correo"];

/*
    *Declaramos $response aquí para usarla ocurra lo que ocurra
    *Si hay un error le haremos decir a $response lo que ocurre
*/
$response = array();

/*Empezamos a controlar el código*/

/*Control 1: debes saber lo que ocurre con la conexión*/

if ($con){
    /*Prefiero variables para todo, me parece que es más limpio, es algo personal*/
    $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios (Usuario, Contraseña, Nombres, Apellidos, Edad, Numero, Correo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

    /*Control 2: ¿El $statement se preparó o no?*/
    if ($statement) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssiis", $Usuario, $Contraseña, $Nombre, $Apellido, $Edad, $Numero, $Correo);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        /*Control 3: ¿Qué pasó en la ejecución?*/

        $contador=mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($statement);

        if ($contador){         
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["mensaje"] = "Se insertaron ".$contador." registros";  

        }else{
            $mensaje=mysqli_stmt_error($statement);     
            $response["success"] = false;  
            $response["mensaje"] = "Error insertando. Datos duplicados o algún dato erróneo: ".$mensaje;  

        }

        /* cerrar sentencia */
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    }else{
        $mensaje=mysqli_stmt_error($statement);     
        $response["success"] = false;  
        $response["mensaje"] = "Error preparando la consulta SQL: ".$mensaje;  

    }   

    /* cerrar conexión (si es preciso)*/
    mysqli_close($con);

}else{
    $mensaje=mysqli_connect_errno().PHP_EOL. mysqli_connect_error();
    $response["success"] = false;  
    $response["mensaje"] = $mensaje;  

}
echo json_encode($response);
```

He explicado todo en los comentarios. Ahora esta línea, puesta al final del todo:  `echo json_encode($response);` te dirá **siempre** lo que está ocurriendo con tu código.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad, estoy iniciandome en php y base de datos,, estoy leyendo un libro pero no sabia como resolver ese problema, con su codigo me manda un solo problema: mysqli_stmt_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given, tratare de resolverlo

Comment: Debes revisar que tienes una tabla llamada `usuarios` y que las columnas tienen el nombre y tipo como se indican aquí: `Usuario, Contraseña, Nombres, Apellidos, Edad, Numero, Correo` . Según el bind, `Numero` y `Correo` deben ser del tipo `INT`. También, los nombres de tabla y columna son *case sensitive*, o sea, que si tu columna se llama por ejemplo `usuario`  en la base de datos y en el INSERT tú pones `Usuario`, el código fallará. Otra cosa que puede estar ocurriendo es que los datos que intentas insertar violen alguna restricción de la BD (duplicados por ejemplo).

Comment: Si eso me estaba dando cuanto ya los corregi y ya me corrio el codigo, de verdad muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso encontré este error y era por que la sentencia SQL la estaba concatenando en dos renglones de código para respetar la longitud máxima recomendada por linea, tal que en lugar de construirla en dos lineas la construí en una sola:

Antes:
$sql = "SELECT SECCION, NOMBREARTICULO, FECHA, PAISDEORIGEN, "
. "PRECIO FROM ARTICULOS WHERE PAISDEORIGEN = ?";

Después:
$sql = "SELECT SECCION, NOMBREARTICULO, FECHA, PAISDEORIGEN, PRECIO FROM ARTICULOS WHERE PAISDEORIGEN = ?";

Comment: El OP no está concatenando nada ...